# async request for python

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

I try to use aiohttp and asyncio to do the request.But I got the error

> ' An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required'

here's my code.How can I fix it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import aiohttp

res = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
movie_list=[]
for link in soup.select('section li a[href]'):
    movie_list.append('https://www.rottentomatoes.com'+link.get('href'))

async def request(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            body = await resp.text(encoding='utf-8')
            soup =BeautifulSoup(body,'lxml')
            movie = []
            async for link in soup.select('tbody tr td a '):
                await movie.append(link.get('href'))

        return  movie

async def main():
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[request(url) for url in movie_list])
    print(results)
    return results
print(movie_list)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(main)
```

Comment: You over-use the async... it is not a magic word. Better read a tutorial about asyncio first. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-asynchronous-programming-in-python-with-asyncio-232e2afa44f6

Comment: Extending to MatrixTai's comment: Just because you're in a coroutine, doesn't mean every for loops need an `async` and every calls need to be `await`ed. Remove `async` when looping through `soup.select` and the `await` from `movie.append` in `request`, as they are not asynchronous.

Comment: thanks for help.I removed the async and await.But still got the error 'An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required'

Comment: Please post the complete exception, with traceback, not just a description of it. Even if it means nothing to you, it tells the people who are trying to help you where the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `loop.run_until_complete(main())`, not just a function `main` (without parenthesis). The next thing is you don't need `async` keyword in `soup.select()`. I also changed a select string, to parse something:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import aiohttp

res = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
movie_list=[]

for link in soup.select('section li a[href]'):
    movie_list.append('https://www.rottentomatoes.com'+link.get('href'))

async def request(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            body = await resp.text(encoding='utf-8')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(body,'lxml')
            movie = []
            # no need to call async for here!
            for link in soup.select('section#top_movies_main table a'):
                movie.append(link['href'])

        return  movie

async def main():
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[request(url) for url in movie_list])
    print(results)
    return results

print(movie_list)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(main())   # you need to create coroutine
```

Prints:

```
['https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_action__adventure_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_animation_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_art_house__international_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_classics_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_comedy_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_documentary_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_drama_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_horror_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_kids__family_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_musical__performing_arts_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_mystery__suspense_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_romance_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_science_fiction__fantasy_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_special_interest_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_sports__fitness_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_television_movies/', 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_western_movies/']
[['/m/mad_max_fury_road', '/m/1013775-metropolis', '/m/wonder_woman_2017', '/m/logan_2017', '/m/1011615-king_kong', '/m/zootopia', '/m/1000355-adventures_of_robin_hood', '/m/star_wars_episode_vii_the_force_awakens', 

... and so on
```